# How to set the key when creating a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to set the key prop from components on the constructor. This is where I got:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { key: Math.random() }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <h2>test</h2>
    )   
  }
}


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          { [<Test/>, <Test/>, <Test/>] }
        </div>
    );  
  }
}

export default App;
```

The App is `ReactDOM` rendered  in a div. However I got the following warning:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.

How can I set the key in the constructor of a component?

**Edit:** Sorry, my question is probably poor worded. I'm specifically looking for a way to set the key of a component inside the component class, on the constructor or one of the callbacks, not from outside. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Avoid using `Math.random` or array index as the key. Better to use an id that comes from an API or some other like uniqueid module. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Thanks! This is only a minimal example to show the error. My main point is: Can I initialize the keys inside a component code, on the constructor or other callback?

Comment: `key` is a prop that a component receives. I do not think it is possible to provide one from within a component. Also, props are immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`key` is a special prop name that you pass into a component. All you do is just assign it. Make sure the keys are all different for identical components.

```
{ [<Test key='1'/>, <Test key='2'/>, <Test key='3'/>] }
```

but this isn't a typical use case of `key`. `key` is almost always used for iterators like `map` that make multiple copies of a component automatically. The conventional way, but strange in this situation, would be like this:

```
{ [1,2,3].map((num, idx) => <Test key={idx}/>)}
```

Of course, your array that you map over would have meaningful data in real use cases. The index number argument of `map` is the typical value to use for a `key`, because it ensures uniqueness for a key.

Comment: [This guy](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) and some others are against using map index as keys. That said, this is the shortest example I could think of, I'm actually creating the components with a button click, and would be weird to set the key on the callback. No way to define the key on the `Item` component code?

Comment: @fotanus Great article and I will definitely keep this in mind in the future. Your question very much depends on how you're going about adding new elements to an array. Do you have an existing array in `this.state` that you're mapping over? Because you could always use `this.setState` to add to that array which should automatically update the elements rendered.

Comment: Yes, on my case the components are in an array on the `App` state. I have added an edit question, since I probably over simplified my original question, please take a look! I'm actually interested in if is possible to set the key prop from inside the component code.

Comment: I have an idea that might work, which I'll give a try out later tonight.

Comment: @fotanus Turns out it's either highly taboo or not even available (it's a private variable). Try and think of a way to fundamentally change the way you're designing your hierarchy to account for this. Sorry, all I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          { [<Test key={Math.random()} />, <Test key={Math.random()}/>, <Test key={Math.random()} />] }
        </div>
    );  
  }
}
```

React throws this error only where the array is being printed out. The keys should be created where the array is being displayed, in your case, on the App component, not on the Test component because there is no array there.

The key property helps on the [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) process.

Fyi: Keys should be unique, you have to make sure they are. Math.random is sort of a random key, but can eventually hit the same number twice.

Comment: Thanks! There is no way to create the key on the component code? This is the shortest example I could think of, I'm actually creating the components with a button click, and would be weird to set the key on the callback.